# Infinitive vs. To Be Gerund

Tags: grammaticality, progressive-aspect

Which of the following sentences is regarded as more grammatical?

1. They appear to like their new neighborhood.

OR

2. They appear to be liking their new neighborhood.

Is it the case that while both may be grammatically proper, each sentence structure above conveys a different meaning and/or area of emphasis?

Comment: There's no particular reason to use the continuous tense (though you can). To 'like the neighbourhood' is, by definition, something ongoing.

Comment: (I would not call this a gerund.)  Compare: "I like it" and "I am liking it".  Then "I like it" refers to now, while "I am liking it" may refer to liking it for a period of time (including now).

Comment: 'Be liking' here is not the unmarked choice. The continuous seems to my ear to open up the statement more (it's less clipped / clinical), inviting speculation on activities etc involved. But this is pragmatics, often open to opinion.

Comment: @GEdgar You are an idiot

Comment: Hi, welcome to English Stack Exchange, thank you for your question, we are glad you are here! Please be sure to take the [Site Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)  and read our [Code of Conduct](https://english.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!